# Getting the count for each id from related table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the count of all pids from table bidding for each tender.

where the tender table has:  id, user_id

and bidding table has: id, tender_id, user_id

for example, I'm opening the page of user_id:39.

which has the following tenders: 1,2,3,4
and the bidding table has the bidding value :

```
id |  Tender_id | user_id  |  
1  |  1         |   40     |
2  |  1         |   41     |
3  |  2         |   40     |
```

Now, I want to get the count for each tender_id which has been binding and show that at this table of tenders for the user of id 39 which will be :

```
   | id | total binding |  total binding|
   | 1  | 2             |   1           |
   | 2  | 1             |   2           |
```

I have used this code :

```
    $dbs= $this->db->select('COUNT(bidding.tender_id) AS count')
where('bidding.tender_id', $tender->id); 
    echo count($dbs);
```

But the result is wrong which giving me that all the result is 1 !!

Any Help?
------- Update ----------
I have used that and getting the wrong result too :

```
$this->db->select('bidding.tender_id' );
                                                                            $this->db->from('bidding');
                                                                            $this->db->join("tenders", "bidding.tender_id = tenders.id", 'left');
                                                                            $where = "bidding.tender_id=".$tender->id;
                                                                            $this->db->where($where);
                                                                            $this->db->group_by('tenders.id');
                                                                            $res = $this->db->get();
                                                                            echo count($res);
```

Comment: There are no pids here.

Comment: Here's it's the bids :   id , Tender_id  ,   user_id  
    1   , 1          , 40 
    2   , 1          , 41 
    3   ,  2         , 40  
Yes ,CodeIgniter

Comment: You can check that from the question as i can't show that at the comment .

Comment: Use group by along with count function. you will get your result.

Comment: Can you please check the update , there's the same wrong result with using group by ?

Comment: @DinaShaldoum What type/class is `$this->db`?

Comment: It's related to the frame work of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$this->db->select('bidding.tender_id, COUNT(*) AS count');
  $this->db->from('bidding');
  $where = "bidding.tender_id=".$tender->id." AND user_id=39";
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->group_by('tender_id');
  $res = $this->db->get();
  echo count($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that question with that query :

```
$this->db->select('bidding.tender_id, COUNT(*) AS count')->where('bidding.tender_id', $tender->id)->group_by('bidding.tender_id')->get('bidding')->result_array() ;
```